MMSI varies under same ShipName over 4-minute duration, sometimes with changes in percentage suffix
I captured AIS messages from aisstream.io and grouped distinct combinations of (ShipName,MMSI) according to similarity in ShipName.  These are shown in the Annex below.  Importantly, these messages are captured over a mere 4-minute time window (approximately).  This corroborates with the time_utc fields in the messages, which have min/max values of:
2024-04-15 23:00:24.770932839 +0000 UTC
2024-04-15 23:04:20.984380767 +0000 UTC

As per this Q&A, the time_utc values are added by the message receiver rather than the sender.
Two ways that grouped ShipName's vary are: (i) by the percentage suffix at the end of the ShipName and (ii) the occassional double space rather than single space between words.
It has been suggested here that the percentage suffix may be a battery level.  How is it that the battery can deplete so quickly over a 4-minute window?
I note that the MMSI sometimes varies between grouped ShipName's.  The MMSI reflects the state under which a vessel is operating.  Again, within a 4-minute window, how can the MMSI change so quickly?
Annex: Distinct pairs of (ShipName,MMSI) grouped by similar ShipName's
            ShipName       MMSI
--------------------  ---------
MR:N2FE         [3%]  109050905
MR:N2FE        [87%]  109050904
MR:N2FE        [88%]  109050904
MR:N2FE        [92%]  109050899
MR:N2FE        [93%]  109050899

HAVELLA BUOY 2 [42%]  941500651
HAVELLA BUOY 2 [45%]  941500651
HAVELLA BUOY 2 [47%]  941500651

       JULIE PAULINE  257922000
JULIE PAULINE  [62%]  941500568
JULIE PAULINE  [64%]  941500568

KVALVIK SENIOR [74%]  941500553
KVALVIK SENIOR [75%]  941500553
KVALVIK SENIOR [79%]  941500992

LISA BUOY 4    [40%]  941500551
LISA BUOY 4    [41%]  941500551
LISA BUOY 4    [42%]  941500551

                -73%  221001237
                -78%  221001175

109120453      [34%]  109120453
109120453      [35%]  109120453

ASMUND SENIOR  [46%]  109080257
ASMUND SENIOR  [64%]  109080259

         BELLA  VITA  368164070
          BELLA VITA  338197303
          BELLA VITA  338338181
          BELLA VITA  503040840

KAMILLA BUOY 2 [52%]  941500839
KAMILLA BUOY 2 [53%]  941500839

MAAKEN BUOY    [67%]  941500718
MAAKEN BUOY    [68%]  941500718

MIKKELSEN B 5  [74%]  941500907
MIKKELSEN B 5  [75%]  941500907

NORSOL 5       [69%]  109050897
NORSOL 5       [70%]  109050897

NY-VIKING B 1  [69%]  941500505
NY-VIKING B 1  [70%]  941500505

OYANES 2       [82%]  109080342
OYANES 2       [83%]  109080342
OYANES 3       [18%]  109080345
OYANES 3       [19%]  109080345

SVARTHAV 2     [11%]  109050943
SVARTHAV 2     [14%]  109050943

      VALENCIA I 90%  533131017
      VALENCIA I 91%  533131017

         YUE LONG  3  477996998
          YUE LONG 3  477996998

